# How to set up git with LibGDX project

Tags: java, android, git, github, libgdx

I have set up a libgdx project with github. The problem is, that i have to specify the path for additional libraries every time i pull from repository. 
[image]

It uses paths from my friend's computer, not from mine. Would storing these libraries in a github repository help?

Comment: Usually, you set up a gradle built application so the eclipse project will be generated by `gradlew eclipse`. So, if anyone will checkout your project on their computer, the pathes will be generated for them dynamically. So no path to **your** gradle cache directory will be saved (except you store the **.classpath** file to the repository).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem by adding additional libraries to my repository.